# url to link to the app store for an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, hyperlink, app-store

Note that I don't want to link to an app on the store.  I want a general store link.  The link should work when tapped from an iOS device.  I don't care if it works under other circumstances or not.

There are multiple questions asking how to link to an app.  But that's a different question.

Comment: you want to navigate the user to AppStore.app ?

Comment: Yes.  I'll be making it a commissioning link.  But just getting to the app and store would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Take one of those app links and remove the app-specific stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick for you.

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewGrouping?cc=gb&id=25206&mt=8&pillIdentifier=iphone